# Constraint that allows only specific characters, MsSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Example table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(255),
    LastName nvarchar(255),
    PhoneNumber varchar(255)
)
```

How can i add constraint that won't allow adding any letters into PhoneNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table person add constraint chk_person_phonenumber
    check (phonenumber not like '%[^0-9]%');
```

This says that `phonenumber` has no characters that are not digits.

Note that you an extend the pattern to allow spaces, hyphens, or parentheses, if you really also want those.

If you really just wanted digits, you could also use `try_convert()`:

```
    check (phonenumber not like '%.%' and
           try_convert(decimal(38, 0), phonenumber) is not null
          )
```

This is not as flexible for expanding the character set, though.

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed, i have read something about CHECK but they only show most basic examples.